# Hivesql question: im trying to format 'datatype: double' to chars of 9 strings but add 0s to leading string if not upto 9 string

Tags: hive

I am trying to remove space or special characters and format 'datatype: double' to chars of 9 strings but add 0s to leading string if not upto 9 string. Each row output have diff amount of strings

Row Record
922,421
1,294,043
22,513,01
24,655

My expectation:
000922421
001294043
002251301
000024655

What i tried: cast(cast(column_name as format '9(9)') as chars(9)). It throws error

Answer (score 0):

Use lpad.

But first remove comma with blank using replace() and then lpad() 9 places with0s.

```
select lpad(replace( '922,421',',',''),9,'0') as col
```